# Sentence Ambiguity

Tags: sentence-meaning

"While driving" and "At home" refer to Sara or William?

> 1. William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her while driving.
> 2. William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her at home.

Comment: Driving refers to William, and at home refers to Sarah.

Comment: That was actually my first guess. But cannot "While driving" be a reduced clause that could mean either "While he is driving" or "While she is driving"? and couldn't be the same for "at home"?

Comment: Faith Alrestom, I think Stephie has precisely answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets's take sentence 2 first:

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her at home.

This is an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), a full sentence could be for example:

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her at **her** home.

Interpreting "home" as "*William's* home*" doesn't make sense here, if William is the one initiating the call, his position would be refered to as **from**, not <del>**at**</del>. So differing prepositions prevent ambiguity in this case.

Sentence 1 appears thus:

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her while driving.

In this case, the full sentence would be some form of:

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her while **[someone is]** driving.

*Grammar-wise*, both "William" and "Sarah" could fill the position.

Yet *logically* speaking William will always know when he's driving, but not necessarily do so when Sarah is, therefore most readers will *assume* the sentence to be:

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her while **he is** driving.

But while this is the most likely case, we can not exclude the meaning to be:

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her while **she is** driving.

So yes, sentence 1 is in fact ambiguous.

Comment: Stephie,  a convincing answer.

Comment: Saying "William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her from home."  this would mean William's home. Right?

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom Correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we presume that the sentences are *grammatically correct*.

The solution to ambiguity lies in the closest association of the parts of the sentence.

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her **while driving**.

What is the nearest word to which 'while driving' can be connected?  Can it be "her"?  No.  The use of "while" prohibits that.  The adjective phrase "while driving" cannot logically connect to a noun or pronoun.  It can only connect to a verb.  What's the nearest verb?  It's "***call***". That is, the phrase expands to

> **not to call** [her] **while driving**

Could it be Sarah who is driving, then?  No, it is William because there is the pronoun "him" preceding that phrase and linking with it.

---

Same analysis helps us unravel the second example.

> William is aware that Sarah told him not to call her **at home**.

What is the closest item to which "at home" can connect?  It is "***her***".  So, who's at home, then?  Sarah.